What causes the plane contrails to bend in the foreground of the eclipse?
This looks almost like refractive index of air is different in the shadowed part, but what would cause that?




I'd think it's more likely air currents caused by the cooling of the air in the shadow. It does get quite a bit cooler.

It is always best to give the source of any photos. There is an extensive discussion of these photos at https://mathstodon.xyz/@tao/112254548031749423.

@DavidBailey: I considered doing that, but I'm curious if that really is what is preferred at stackexchange. Unless the context gives information about the physical phenomenon in question I feel like when I've to provide context in the past it's been edited out by others to distill the post to just the question at hand. But perhaps I've just provided bad context in the past, who knows.
